# data-target data-toggle is not working with vscode

Tags: php, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I had create a php code for doing CRUD application,To-do-list. Then I run it on my browser and it is not pop-up and do nothing, when I click the "Add Task" button.

```
<button type="button" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success">Add Task</button>
```

check my full code on [codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/yBfpfGc1Vy).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script> 
        src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"
    </script>
    <script>
        src = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity = "sha384-Rc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA712mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
        crossorigin = "anonymous"
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" intergrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg320mUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>CRUD App</title>
</head>
```

What should I do, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where is your `#myModal` element in HTML ?

Comment: data-target value should be the targeted div id by which ckick event opened the modal

Comment: this is my full code, on [codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/yBfpfGc1Vy) thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `<div  id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">` like below

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" intergrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg320mUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>CRUD App</title>
    
    <button type="button" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success">Add Task</button>
    
    
    
    
    <div  id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thank you ! It work. the problem is my script maybe not correct.I just use the code that you gave me, on the first 3 lines. Thank you very much.